# How to gzip a .OBJ file is it possible in the .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, compression, gzip, .obj

Hi I couldn't find much online on how to gzip a .obj file I did manage to compress it changing the files extension to .gz but this isn't desirable in my case.
I want to gzip the .obj file as it's 13mb is this possible to do with the .htaccess file and how would one go about it? (keeping the .obj extension).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible. Using `mod_deflate` module and modify the **.htaccess** as follow:

```
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
    <ifmodule mod_mime.c>
        Addtype text/plain .obj
    </ifmodule>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
</ifmodule>
```

**Before** compression:

```
> curl --compressed -so /dev/null http://localhost/foo.obj -w '%{size_download}'
464590
```

**After** compression:

```
> curl --compressed -so /dev/null http://localhost/foo.obj -w '%{size_download}'
148261
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks for that! works like a charm got it from 13.4mb to 1.8mb can't thank you enough!